# How to have Outerglow using Pen

Tags: wpf

I am drawing a dash line using `Pen`. One of my requirements is to have an Outerglow effect around dash.

So far I have found Outerglow effect can be achieved using `DropShadowEffect` but I am not sure how to do it with a Pen.  Can Dash styles be customized to have Effects?

```
var highlightPen = new Pen(new SolidColorBrush(CellBorderColor), 2) {DashStyle = DashStyles.Dash};

DC.DrawRectangle(new SolidColorBrush((Color) ResourceDictionary["HighlightedCellFontColor"]), highlightPen,
            new Win.Rect(PositionX - 3, PositionY - 3, Width + 5, Height + 5));
```

Where `DC` is the `DrawingContext`